# ASIHTTPRequest only works when i hardcode the strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem that really makes me scratch my head. There seems to be no logical reason why this is happening. If i hardcode the string into the NSURL it works. But if I pass a NSString instead it doesnt work. I have confirmed that the NSString is identical to hardcoded string by NSLog both of them.

Code that works. Server returns a 200 responce code.

```
        //NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/%@",monograph.uri];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.server.com/api/monograph/com/3894.json"];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request; 
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUsername:appDelegate.key];
    [request setPassword:appDelegate.secret];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Code that fails. Server returns 204 response code for this:

```
NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/%@",monograph.uri];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request; 
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUsername:appDelegate.key];
    [request setPassword:appDelegate.secret];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

When i NSLog urlStr it contains:

```
http://www.server.com/api/monograph/com/3894.json
```

What am i missing? There must be something to explain it -.-

Regards,
Code

EDIT

checked the length of both strings and they are both same length so seems not white spaces or anything hidden in there.

Comment: Are you sure that  monograph.uri is @"api/monograph/com/3894.json"? Put an nslog on it.

Comment: Are you sure it's a response code 204?  204 means "success but no body". Is this a typo for 404?

Comment: No its definitely 204. When it should really be 200. Since thats the response i get when i hardcode the URL string.

Comment: Where is monograph.uri coming from? It must be a codepage issue with the property that NSLog is masking. Do you have control of the server to try and see the incoming requests?

Answer (score 1):

Cut all the new lines/spaces from the string, this is one possible reason. And sometimes the log doesn't show you the new lines.

try

> NSString * s = [monograph.uri stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
>
> NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/%@",s];

Comment: did you do exactly this: 

> NSString *s = [monograph.uri stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
> NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/%@", s];
? 
(I also edited the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the NSURL object you get from the string variable is not nil? That could help you home in on the location of the problem.

Also, you might try escaping the string variable, just incase something funny is getting in with the stringWithFormat call.

Comment: What do you mean by escaping the string var? Thanks -Code

Comment: string = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: Tried that and alas there was no change.

Comment: I NSLog the  NSURL *url and it contains the correct URL. This is nuts -.-

Comment: Try creating both NSURLs (the one that works and the one that doesnt), and check if their urlStrings are equal. Then, start with the hard-coded URL, and use that NSURL's urlString to create the second one, and see if the second one works. Yes, this is nuts.